# Keep only differences (and the some lines above and below) between 2 CSV files

Tags: bash, shell

I'm very new to shell scripting and wasn't sure how to go about doing this.
Suppose  I have two files:

```
file1.csv | file2.csv
--------------------
Apples      Apples
Dogs        Dogs
Cats        Cats
Grapes      Oranges
Batman      Thor
Borgs       Daleks
Kites       Kites
Blah        Blah
xyz         xyz
```

How do I only keep the differences in each file, and 2 lines above the start of the differences, and 2 lines after? For example, the output would be:

```
file1.csv  |  file2.csv
-----------------------
Dogs          Dogs
Cats          Cats
Grapes        Oranges
Batman        Thor
Borgs         Daleks
Kites         Kites
Blah          Blah
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use the `diff` command

Comment: I'd need the changes to be made in the files themselves though. Would diff be able to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a job for `diff`.

```
diff -u2 file1.csv file2.csv | sed '1,3d;/@@/,+2d' > diff
```

The `diff` command will produce a patch style difference containing meta information of the files in the form:

```
--- file1.csv   2017-05-12 15:21:47.564801174 -0700
+++ file2.csv   2017-05-12 15:21:52.462801174 -0700
@@ -2,7 +2,7 @@
```

Any block of difference will have header like `@@ -2,7 +2,7 @@`. We want to throw these away using `sed`.

`1,3d` - means delete the top 3 lines

`/@@/,+2d` - delete any lines containing `@@` and the next 2 lines after it. This is not needed for your case but is good to be included here in case your input suddenly has multiple blocks of differences.

The result of the above commands will produce this list.

```
 Dogs
 Cats
-Grapes
-Batman
-Borgs
+Oranges
+Thor
+Daleks
 Kites
 Blah
```

The contents has a 1 character prefix, `' '` is common to both, `'-'` is only on `file1.csv` while `'+'` is only on `file2.csv`. Now all we need is to distribute these to the 2 files.

```
sed '/^+.*/d;s/^.//' diff > file1.csv
sed '/^-.*/d;s/^.//' diff > file2.csv
```

The `sed` commands here will filter the file and write the proper contents to each of the input files.

`/^+.*/d` - lines starting with `'+'` will be deleted.

`s/^.//` - will remove the 1 character prefix which was added by `diff`.

`/^-.*/d` - lines starting with `'-'` will be deleted.

Finally, remove the transient file `diff`.

Comment: would you mind giving a breakdown for what is happening in the `sed` command

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question! I really appreciate it. I second @hmedia1, would you mind explaining what sed does here?